# Where store Tests (project structure - best practice)?

Tags: go, project-structure, clean-architecture, django-project-architect, go-testing

We have many different ways to implement project structure in GO.

My question is where the **best way** to store tests implementation:

1. separately (as `Java` *Maven/Gradle* standard)

   ```
   ├── pkg
   │   ├── colocator
   │   │   ├── some_impl.go
   │   │   └── ...
   │   ├── common
   │   │   └── ...
   │   └── dashboard
   │       └── ...
   ├── test
   │   │  └── internal
   │   │      └── some_test_utils.go
   │   ├── pkg
   │   │   ├── colocator
   │   │   │   ├── mocks
   │   │   │   │   └── some_mock.go
   │   │   │   └── some_impl_test.go
   │   │   ├── ...
   ```
2. in place

   ```
   ├── pkg
   │   ├── colocator
   │   │   ├── mocks
   │   │   │   └── some_mock.go
   │   │   ├── some_impl.go
   │   │   └── some_impl_test.go
   ```
3. etc...

?

Comment: Test for package A are store in the folder of package A. In Go you do not use mocks (in the sense of Java or PHP). Take a look at how the Go stdlib is organized.

Comment: And what about mocking interfaces (self or use external libs)?

Comment: I try to use `Clean Architecture` approach => I have to crete and implement interfaces and I have to mock ones in tests

Comment: This seems to be a common misunderstanding of  Clean Architecture that you have to use mocks. You don't. Please learn about all variants of test doubles. Again: Take a look at the stdlib; it uses almost no mocks.

Comment: If you read anything about Go testing, you'll find the recommendation is always the second option. The first option would only allow for black-box testing of public API, you couldn't test anything unexported.

Comment: @Agrian - How could I testing complex `composition` without mocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second implementation is the 'correct' go way. Also you dont have to worry about those tests taking up space or something. The compiler ignores when you build the package.

Comment: Thx. but I want to verify what is the most convenient way to organize project